# How can this be: I can switch to a keyboard layout which is not installed (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-layout, locale

I live in Germany but have my Windows 7 system set to the English (UK) format (except for location, which is set to Germany). The Windows itself is an English one. I have only an American English and a Russian keyboard layouts installed. In the last weeks I noticed that a German layout appears now and then, and behaves really weirdly: I can switch to it, but it's not in the list of installed layouts.

I can remove it by first adding it to and the deleting it from the installed layouts. But I'd like it to stop appearing on its own. I couldn't spot when it appears yet. This problem is not seen too often. I've found two more threads on it, without a clear solution: http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/99464-english-keyboard-layout-appears-its-own.html and [Problem removing US keyboard layout from input languages](https://superuser.com/questions/236618/problem-removing-us-keyboard-layout-from-input-languages).

[image: screenshot - ghost DE language]

Also I've checked that the language for non-Unicode programs is German. I wonder if it can cause problems. To be honest, I don't remember setting it but may be I did. Anyway, I am not using any old programs.

[image: screenshot - language for non-Unicode programs]

Any comments or suggestions?

Comment: Check for Microsoft Office IME running on startup, see http://superuser.com/a/527430

Comment: @PavelChuchuva I don't even have Office installed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no answer has been offered so far, I'll post my solution as long as it works and nothing better is suggested. As mentioned in the question, my language for non-Unicode programs (Control Panel > Region and Language > Administrative) was set to German. I have changed it to English (US) and since then the German layout does not reappear.