# How do I remove English (US) from Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, input-languages

I've got a slightly annoying problem. My locale is English (UK), but occasionally my keyboard randomly switches to English (US) on Windows 8.1. I see that the task bar has a language selector, which when I click on it displays two languages:

[image]

Most of the time it stays on UK, but occasionally randomly switches to US. When I go into the Language section of the control panel, only English UK exists:

[image]

In `Advanced Settings` I've specifically set the input method to be English (UK), but English (US) persists in its obstinate existence.

Why is the 'US keyboard' there? How do I get rid of it?

*edit* There is only one language listed under 'input settings':

[image]

Comment: You may leave **UK language**, but change its keyboard to **US**.

Answer (score 110):

I understand your frustration. This will work!

**Control Panel > Language**

If 'English (United States)' is not a visible option then re-add it by clicking 'Add a language'

Once added click 'options' on the US language and add an input language.

Add the United Kingdom input method.

Remove the United States input method.

go back to 'Change your language preferences' and remove the English (United States) language you had added.

Hopefully Windows updates will fix this soon.

Comment: This will also remove the 'ENG' tab from the taskbar.

Comment: I had exactly this issue (only UK English listed in the settings, but US English appearing as well in the taskbar) and adding, then removing US English within the settings worked for me.

Comment: It works! It is very strange though - It doesnt make any logic to me as to why adding a whole other input and removing it should do this.  But thank you!

Comment: Lol Windows will never stop suprising me :D Thanks!

Comment: +1 You saved me. I hate those windows bugs. Linux will always be the best :P

Comment: Thank you!  Now I can have my UK and Estonian layouts without the annoying US one getting in the way!

Comment: This also works for Windows 10

Comment: For me in Australia, this only works until a reboot, then the language icon comes back, showing English (US). On the Languages screen, all I see is English (Australia). What worked for me is to switch off the "input indicator system icon" as per the procedure here:

http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-remove-and-hide-the-language-indicator-icon-in-windows-10/

Comment: This is still a bug in Windows 10 1607. Unbelievable. Luckily your fix still works.

Comment: It works for some time on Windows 10, but then later the removed language returns back. Not sure, what triggers it - maybe some update, maybe something else. In my case it is not entire language, but one of keyboard input methods for Latvian language which keeps returning back even after being forcibly added and removed. Oh, Microsoft, why is your Control Panel out of sync with the taskbar...

Comment: Back to square 1. There is no longer any such option in Control Panel.

Answer (score 10):

The right answer to the question «***How do I remove automatically added keyboard layouts?***»:
https://superuser.com/a/484595/128312

Answer (score 2):

this may also help - though it may be a variation on a theme (of Amits answer).
I'd tried all the other options - but to no avail - English (United States) kept reappearing on the list and the keyboard input was US.

This worked for me:
Changed Control Panel to Large Icons (rather than Category - my preferred Mode)

Selected **Language**.

From the **Change your language preference** window (which showed both UK and US English).
Selected **English (United Kingdom)**
Then **Options** / **Add an input method**. I then selected **United Kingdom Extended**. (I already had the United Kingdom). It selected the new one ok.

Then back to previous **Change your language preference** window. Selected **English (United States)** and then **Remove**. It removed it - this time permanently.

I then rebooted and the correct UK Keyboard input method was working (Pressing @ got @ not ")

A very odd and convoluted process to get an essential result.

Comment: This worked for me too on Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

To remove a language via  IME (*Input Method Editor*) :

Go to **All Control Panel Items > Language  > Language options**.

There you can see **Input Methods**. Remove the US Keyboard from there.Hit **save**. *voilà*.

**Update :**

Since there is no input method other than UK English , I have to assume that there may be some program that requests the US English Keyboard layout ( *Programs like [icq](http://www.icq.com/en) are claimed to do that* ). Or it may be due to Microsoft Office IME running on startup.

I personally do not know much about this issue since I use the US Keyboard layout by default.But, I think that you might have to give a try for the solutions listed here for a [similar question](https://superuser.com/q/236618/241659) in Windows 7.

Comment: I updated my question - I think I got the same dialog you're referring to, and there's only 'United Kingdom' listed under 'Input method'.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem

I have a solution, but it's not a permanent one.

You need to add the specific keyboard layout that your computer seems to have added by itself, then click apply.

After that you need to remove that specific keyboard layout and click apply, the language bar should now be gone and you should not be able to switch to ENG US anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Still not fixed by Windows Update as of today...
This problem seems to occur only on machines that have been upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1, though I'm not 100% sure of that.

The solutions above didn't work for me. My keyboard layout was stuck on English (US) and my keyboard is in Dutch (Belgian Point).

How I fixed it:

1. Open **configuration panel** > **language**
2. Open the options for **English (US)** *(I cannot delete this entry, it's always back after closing and opening this settings screen again)*
3. Add the keyboard layout you want to **English (US)**
4. Delete the existing keyboard layout, this should be **English (US)**
5. **Save** the settings
6. Switch the keyboard layout using the **charms bar** > **settings** or another method to the input method you need.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest going to the Advanced settings menu and take a look at the 'Apply language settings to the welcome screen, system accounts and new user link'. I changed all the options to read English (United Kingdom) - United Kingdom, copied them to the Welcome screen, system account and New user account and thankfully now have no sign of any option to select the US layout!!!