# Windows 8.1 - can I have a UK English Keyboard layout with a usable ` key?

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-layout, language

On Windows 8.1 it seems as though I can't have the keyboard layout I want - I am based in the UK and if I set my language to `UK English` it seems to think that means I want a US keyboard layout with it's zany interpretation of where the `@` and `"` symbols belong, quite contrary to what is printed on my keys.

If I switch to the United Kingdom Extended layout, I get my basic layout correct but now if I want to use the backtick ( which I do if I'm posting on a StackExchange site ) it has turned into an annoying auto-deadkey and I can't find any way to turn it off. I know I can follow it with a space but why should I have to? *The Symbol is right there on the key!*

Is there a way to have a UK keyboard layout on Windows 8.1 without breaking the behaviour of my keyboard with unwanted and unexpected deadkeys?

Comment: That is not normal behaviour. What keyboard do you have? Does it have its own driver?

Comment: It's a Logitech wireless keyboard - I haven't found anything that seems to relate the keyboard specifically to this problem and I have the same problem with my laptop's built-in keyboard, so I think it is a Windows thing rather than a keyboard issue.

Comment: Do you have a keyboard that is US or UK based? What is the symbol above the 4 key? dollar or uk pound?

Comment: The keyboard has £ on the 3 key.

Answer (score 2):

#### can I have a UK English Keyboard layout with a usable ` key?

You need to configure the keyboard to use the **non-extended** version that works with your keyboard layout.

---

#### Windows 7

- `Start` > `Control Panel` > `Region and Language`
- Select the `Keyboard and Languages` tab
- Press `Change keyboards`
- Press `Add`
- If you have a UK based keyboard layout select `English (United Kingdom)` > `Keyboard` > `Show more` ... > `United Kingdom` (**not** `United Kingdom Extended`)

  [image]
- Press OK a few times

---

#### Windows 8.1

See [Add a keyboard layout](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/change-keyboard-layout).

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't fix the problem - the UK English non-extended variant appears to have the US style `@` and `"` switch. It also has `#` instead of the pound sign. In fact I'd be tempted to guess that in spite of having selected the English UK keyboard, Windows is still running the US one under the bonnet. Have tried removing English US as a language to see if that helps.

Comment: Which actual keyboard layout do you have US or UK? (see [British and American keyboards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards#PC_keyboards) for examples of each)

Comment: Yes, try English (United Kingdom) as the language option.

Comment: Did you make the non-extended version your default keyboard (and remove all other keyboard variants)?

Comment: I have UK English as a language (I'm in the UK) but English (US) as a keyboard (I have a US keyboard on my laptop - bought in Holland). Everthing works as expected. So language can be different to keyboard ...

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem turned out to be the answer to another question: [How do I remove English-US from Windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/685078/how-do-i-remove-english-us-from-windows-8-1)

Specifically I needed to add a `UK English` input method to the `US English` language. Once I had selected that, I could remove the `US English` language and now I got to keep the UK Keyboard layout for some reason. Doesn't make much sense, but at least it works!