# Windows 10: only 1 keyboard language but keyboard layout keeps changing

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, language

How is it possible I have only one keyboard layuout but Windows 10 keeps changing my layout to US? I am not sure when it happens exactly but it does few times a day and makes me crazy.

I have disabled keyboard shortcuts for <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> but can't get rid of <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

I have only one language: English (United States) with Windows display language 'English' and Polish (Programmers) Keyboard layout.

Inputs:

[image]

But language bar is still visible in tray and I can switch keyboard layout with <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> like here:

Language Bar:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: See a similar question I answered [here](http://superuser.com/questions/1025105/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-input-option-in-windows-10/1025112#1025112) - effectively add the keyboard and then remove it again.

Comment: I just spent last hour getting to this point and my god is this the stupidest thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the keyboard to your current or default language.
If it is default after you add it, set your preferred keyboard to default.
If it isn't, set it to default and then switch the default back to your prefered keyboard.

You should now be able to remove the *bad* keyboard layout.