# Remove 'English US' keyboard Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, keyboard

Probably it has been asked before but couldn't find the answer. I'm using Windows 8 as I can't update right now (due lots of work that has to be done with the laptop).

This is what I have when I click the 'ENG INTL/US' keyboard selector in the taskbar:

[image]

Now, I went to the language selector in control panel, just because I want to remove the US keyboard since sometimes I'm accidentally changing to it when programming and it's really annoying.

This is all I have:

[image]

And when I double click on it:

[image]

I don't know what's wrong. My system language is English.

Comment: Check here: http://superuser.com/questions/1025105/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-input-option-in-windows-10/1025112#1025112

Comment: You will need to install a different keyboard layout in order to remove the keyboard layout in question.  You currently only have one installed.