# Remove keyboard option from Windows

Tags: keyboard-layout

I use danish localization option and danish keyboard layout most of the time. But when I am programming I use US keyboard layout. But Windows have added

[image]

But I cant seem to remove it anywhere

[image]

The problem is that I often just use ALT + LSHIFT to shift between DA layout and US layout, but I cant do this now as it shifts between DAN and ENG/DA which is still DA layout

I can use Win + space, but its not optimal

Another option would be if I could set default layout per application and not having to set it each time I open an application

Edit:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under "Region & language settings" select "English (Untied States)". Three buttons should pop up, one of which is "Options". (Shown below for UK Eng.)

[image: win10 region and language settings screen]

If you click that it will bring you to a list of Keyboard layouts for that language, where (if you click one) they can also be removed.

[image: win10 language options screen]

In case the Danish layout is not listed, first add and then remove it as described [in this post](https://superuser.com/a/1025157/61297).

Comment: Adding and removing the keyboard worked