# how to remove a duplicate keyboard in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I'm having 2 additional typing languages (since last week's Windows update) and cannot find an intuitive way to remove them.

I need only 2 typing languages (Hebrew and English), How should I remove the last 2 `English (United Kingdom)` language options?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the solution offered in the forum post [Reomve keyboard option](https://superuser.com/questions/1231049/remove-keyboard-option-from-windows)?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I worked my way around it

1. Add `English (United Kingdom)` language
2. Remove `English (United Kingdom)` language
3. Reboot

[image]

Comment: not selecting this as answer since this band-aid will break on the next major windows update

Comment: This worked for me, thank you!