# Can't remove unneeded keyboard layouts - no such setting anywhere

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-layout

After I have installed Office 2016 Home and Student (en-us version) it automatically added two new keyboard layouts - English UK and English International in addition to my existing other layouts (English US and Russian). I'm trying to get rid of these new keyboard layouts but I absolutely cannot find an option to remove them ANYWHERE - not in Control Panel, not in Settings...

I have no "languages" section in Control panel, no "choose your langauge preferences" or whatever. In the new Settings thing these new languages are not shown in the list of languages, I can't remove them!

Does anybody know how to remove these new keyboard layouts? And why did Office add them in the first place?

Screenshots of my settings:

[image]
[image]
[image]

None of these solutions worked for me:

[Remove automatically added keyboard inputs and prevent them from coming back (Windows 10)](https://superuser.com/questions/1025105/remove-automatically-added-keyboard-inputs-and-prevent-them-from-coming-back-wi/1025112)

Comment: If anyone still finds ENG-International keyboard layout returning constantly after triggering a certain hotkey, the easiest workaround (not a solution) is to press `WinKey`+`Spacebar`. This will cycle through all available keyboard layouts enabled on your machine, and you can easily switch out to the right ENG keyboard layout.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a keyboard layout in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you cannot find these languages under
*PC Settings > Time & Language > Region & language > Languages*,
use regedit to navigate to
`HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload`.

You will find there the list of keyboards that are preloaded at boot.
Find the added keyboard layouts by their identifiers from the list of
[Keyboard Identifiers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-language-pack-default-values),
and delete them.

Just in case, export this registry entry as backup.

EDIT: A more comprehensive answer can be found
[here](https://superuser.com/a/1340511/8672).

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, this key gets re-created after reboot, can't delete it forever it seems

Comment: Does this happen if you boot into Safe Mode?

Comment: I managed to finally get rid of these keyboard layouts by setting the values under `Preload` key to `0`. I'm not sure why this worked. Since then they have been changed back to some other non-zero values but I haven't had this problem again. So I guess this answer can be accepted.

Comment: @harrymc I'd like to add just one thing - editing `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload` didn't help me, but editing `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload` did help. I thing it would be nice to include this into your answer as this may help as well.

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak: You will find a more comprehensive answer of mine on this subject [here](https://superuser.com/a/1340511/8672).

Comment: @szx: Thanks, setting them to 0 worked for me! Let's see how persistent this will be for me.

Comment: 12 days (and a reboot) later, the solution in szx's comment is still working fine :)

Answer (score 30):

I had a similar problem to the OP: for the English language, I had US, Canadian Multilingual Standard as well as Canadian French as keyboard layouts and I could not remove the last two.

As I do not have administrator rights on my work PC, I could not use @harrymc's solution by editing the registry but I am able to edit language options. I tried the following and it worked for me:

1. **Add** the extra unwanted keyboard layouts using the *PC Settings > Time & Language > Language* menu so they're all actually listed.
2. Save.
3. Afterwards, come back to the Languages screen and remove the extra layouts.
4. Again, press Save.

I'm not quite sure how nor why but now those extra keyboard layouts are gone.

EDIT: I'm not sure if it's new or it existed when I added that solution but this solution does not persist through reboots.

Comment: This should be marked as an answer. 
In addition I had do add all keyboard layouts for unwanted Languages in my settings according to what was listed in my Language Bar - English (United Kingdom) - English US
then set Windows Display Language to English (United States)
and then I've removed English (United Kingdom)

Comment: In Windows 10 21H1 there is no Save button in those Settings pages. It seem to save immediately when you change anything.

Comment: this answer work to me וp to now, but now is stop work

Comment: This helps till the next restart of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I'm on an English (GB) language-pack and locale PC, but I want the English keyboard to be only *United States-International*.

I found [this article](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-10-keeps-adding-keyboard-layouts) which along with [@harrymc's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1360627/9825) solved the issue.

1. Add and remove all redundant keboard layouts
2. Override input method (PS):

   ```
   Set-WinDefaultInputMethodOverride -InputTip "0809:00020409"
   ```

   Substitute `0809:00020409` with the desired keyboard layout from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-input-locales-for-windows-language-packs) list.
3. Add a new DWORD key named *IgnoreRemoteKeyboardLayout* under *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout*, and set its value to `1`.
4. Reboot.