# Windows 10, remove unwanted keyboard language not in preferences

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, language

I have *French (Belgium)* active as a keyboard language:

[image]

But's not in the Language preferences, so I'm not able to remove it:

[image]

The annoying thing is that my default language is qwerty (as is my keyboard), French Belgium is azerty. It gets switched occassionally on accident (eg alt-shift) or (maybe) after windows updates.

> Where can I remove this unwanted keyboard language?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1469157/1482432

Comment: Manually adding the unwanted language + removing it did the trick, as explained on the link. Thanks for adding! (I failed to see it somehow)