# Delete a keyboard layout in Windows 10 21H2

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, windows-10-v21h2

There are already lots of questions and answers about this, but all of them are outdated. None of the screenshots shown there look like what I have in my system.

I have Windows 10 version 21H2 and after upgrading my Intel graphics driver and rebooting Windows, I have an additional keyboard layout installed. My physical keyboard has a German layout. I don't need or want anything else than what's printed on the keys in front of me. Now the task bar has that additional big language selector button that offers me to switch to the US English layout.

How can I get rid of that? At least the button but preferably also the English layout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1668489/windows-10-remove-unwanted-keyboard-language-not-in-preferences) question

Comment: Well, maybe a duplicate, but it has no working solution. (The fix is temporary and the extra layout reappears after reboot.) Time to ask again?

Comment: You have read the answers to all 3 duplicates? Which solution(s) didn't work exactly? It's time to offer a bounty on the existing questions not create another iteration of the same question

Comment: Can't offer a bounty on an answered question, can I? The first duplicate doesn't have any details, just links to the second duplicate that has accepted a non-working answer. What can I do? Choose another questions platform? I could modify my question to explicitly ask for a *permanent* solution that survives reboots.

Comment: You can offer a bounty on any open question.  I am talking about the duplicate that has 13 answers.