# How do I remove keyboards in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

When I hit Windows + Spacebar on Windows 10, following menu appears:

[image]

I want to only keep two of them (Marathi and English (India)) so that I can quickly swap between them with Windows + Space keypress.

I dont find option to remove rest of two in below settings panel:

[image]

There is no Language settings in Control panel too:

[image]

[image]

Also none of the answers on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1092246/how-to-prevent-windows-10-from-automatically-adding-keyboard-layouts-i-e-us-ke) page seem to help. How do I remove rest of two?

Comment: Look in Settings, Language, Typing, Advanced keyboard settings. I think you can set keyboards there.  I just use one and this works for me.

Comment: Found "Input Language Hot Keys" option [here](https://i.postimg.cc/G259NygF/image.png). It works for US English keyboard, but not the one with Google input tools. Hitting key press for Google input tools language does not do anything. Any guesses?

Comment: I am not certain if you have more than one keboard

Comment: [This](https://i.postimg.cc/024V9WFm/image.png) is how it looks. `Ctrl+Shift+1` simply doesnt work.

Comment: If nothing above has worked, you may not be able to remove the extra keyboard entries

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1360623/cant-remove-unneeded-keyboard-layouts-no-such-setting-anywhere?rq=1) should resolve your problem

Answer (score 1):

To delete a keyboard layout, go to Settings > Time and Language, Language, Click on your Preferred Language, then click Options. Add or remove a keyboard here.

It irks me so much that Microsoft changes things JUST a little, without any apparent reason, and then all the help or tutorials you find don't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a keyboard layout, go to Settings > Time & language > Language & region > Language and then left-click and delete on the one you want to remove.