# What settings should I define in Windows 10? Location: France, Keyboard: Norwegian, Language: English

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

My question is relatively simple.

The ultimate goal of it is to avoid this unwanted behavior:
[unwanted keyboards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnUds.png)

if you check on the Internet or here on superuser.com you'll find long topics with bypassing solutions, approximate descriptions, outdated information, etc.
For instance this one: [Can't remove unneeded keyboard layouts - no such setting anywhere](https://superuser.com/questions/1360623/cant-remove-unneeded-keyboard-layouts-no-such-setting-anywhere)

**So here's my setup**

- I live in Metropolitan France.
- My keyboard has a Norwegian layout
- I want my system in English -> display language
- I want to use the metric system and
  European format for date: day/month/year, €/euro for money, etc.
- And above all, I only want ONE keyboard layout on Windows.

**The question is**

How to have a single keyboard layout on Windows despite having a complex language/location/locale setup

**To answer some questions in advance**

I don't want to change my keyboard, it's a gaming keyboard, I'm fine with it.

I don't want a French layout, I'm used to type accents with the Norwegian keyboard, the only character that I can't type with my keyboard is "le c cedille", and I'm fine without it ^^

I don't want to switch to Linux -> love Linux, but I need Windows on that PC :'(

Comment: I doubt you will be able to have your interface in English and NOT have the associated keyboard installed.  Language Packs on modern versions of Windows link both of those interfaces (keyboard and the associated interface language) into a single package. It is my opinion what you want is not possible.  You can choose any keyboard layout, but if you want your interface in English, the English keyboard will have to be installed. What you describe isn't all that complex.  Your choice of units isn't unusual and is not connected to your language pack, or interface language.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound for your comment!

I am "this close" to try and build a tool in the style of "power toys" for Windows, just to handle this case of unneeded keyboard layouts.

It's crazy that we can't setup exactly what we want in 2023 regarding such typical and mundane aspects Oo