# Windows 10: display keyboard layout in taskbar?

Tags: windows-10

On Windows 10 Enterprise, how do I get the taskbar to show the keyboard layout?

It used to look like:

[image]

which is what I want, but now it shows only the language, like:

[image]

I didn't change any of the related settings.

I'd also be fine with it showing only the keyboard layout, and not the language.

Comment: Please [edit] you question and add the following findings: (1) if you have more than one language active (or better: which ones).  (2) if you attempted to restart the computer (sounds silly but lately in Windows 10 I had problems with national keyboards which were resolved by restart. It looks there is some [new bug](https://superuser.com/questions/1025105/remove-automatically-added-keyboard-inputs-and-prevent-them-from-coming-back-wi/1025112#comment1940958_1025157) related to multiple languages/keyboards which did not met last year but which I met multiple times this year.)

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the computer fixed it. Thanks to @miroxlav.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question and posting what fixed the problem.  Comments are transient, so it would be helpful to include the relevant information from miroxlav's comment within the answer.  In this case, it's a workaround for a bug.  Typically, though, problems that disappear with a reboot are considered unreproducible hiccups, so the questions tend to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue but with another solution:
I had accidentally set up both UK and US English as display languages, and had one layout for each. The result was the same behaviour.

The solution in this case was to remove one of the display languages and add both input languages under the one that remained.