# Why I have another Arabic keyboard in windows 10 or 11?

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, regional-settings, arabic

I am using Windows 11 with English language and an Arabic (Libya) keyboard.

[image: Language & Region Settings Screenshot]

But some how I found an Arabic (Saudi Arabia) keyboard added.

[image: Keyboard Layout Screenshot]

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear in Language & Region settings to remove it.

Could you please help to overcome this issue.

Thak you

Comment: I have solve my issue from MS Office language settings, as I found two languages. So, I have removed one. Windows language settings  doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case with a "non-removable" English (Hong Kong SAR) keyboard, when my display language was English (United States).

And then I found where a setting where it was "hiding":
Language & Region > Administrative Language Settings > Administrative > Welcome screen and new user accounts > Copy settings...
(The welcome screen used that keyboard)

After applying "Copy your current settings to..." (tick both boxes) and restarting, it disappeared.

---

I also vaguely remember a case in Windows 10 where, if I choose "Regional Format" to be "English (Hong Kong SAR)", the keyboard will appear, but I can't reproduce it in my Windows 11 PC.

Comment: All Display & Input language is English and all format is Arabic (Libya)

Comment: @YousefAlbakoush Apparently you need to add "Arabic (Saudi Arabia)" to the list first, then remove it. https://superuser.com/questions/1025105/remove-automatically-added-keyboard-inputs-and-prevent-them-from-coming-back-wi/1025157#1025157 If, after restarting, you still find it added back, then it's probably a setting in "Welcome screen and new user accounts".

Comment: Anyway, I found that my answer is basically the same as https://superuser.com/a/1494394/1686346 and https://it42.cc/2018/11/04/windows-10-unwanted-keyboard-layout-fixed/ (I got the links from the other question)

Comment: Unfortunately,  Adding and removing that language doesn't solve the problem