# How do I type the backtick on a standard US QWERTY keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

I seem to be unable to type the backtick without using an alt code. However, the `~` works fine, and the key can be used as a hotkey in games/programs, just cannot be typed. How would I fix this?

Comment: The key types tilda while pressing with Shift key, and types nothing or something instead of backtick (what char?) without Shift? If so check 1) the keyboard-captured programs (autoconverters, autoreplacers, macrodefiners, etc.); 2) keyboard mapping files integrity.

Comment: nothing comes out, where would I find the mapping files?

Comment: Use [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339) to view (and edit if needed) your current keyboard layout.

Comment: it seems that button, regardless of its binding, will not output unless I press it while holding shift, which is odd.

Comment: Seems to work in safe mode

Comment: If so boot in selective mode (run MSCONFIG), disable some autostart entries (half, then quarter, and so on) and search the entry which cause this strange effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using the [US-International layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#US-International) which has <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and several [dead keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) to type accented characters. It isn't the default keyboard layout for the US

[image: US keyboards]

The simplest solution is to change to the US layout which is the default for the USA, and then you can type `` ` `` as normal. Just open start menu, type *Language* to open language settings and remove the US-International layout and select the plain **US** layout

[image: add language]

[image: language list]

The US QWERTY layout below the International is the desired one

For more information see

- [How to remove unneeded ENG International keyboard layout from Windows 10 permanently?](https://superuser.com/q/1429636/241386)
- [How to delete a keyboard layout in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/957552/241386)
- [How to Add or Remove Keyboard Layouts in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/102916-add-remove-keyboard-layouts-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: Usually you can change between your keyboard layouts by pressing `left Alt` + `left Shift`. By having only 2 layouts / languages active you can be very fast to switch on&off your backtick above the tab key (US layout). Notice: Windows settings allow you to *use a different input method for each app window*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain exactly which Keyboard/Language input types this applies to, however, for some of the International layouts, backtick [& also single quote] get special treatment.

Because they can also be used as combining characters, if you type one, then follow it with a vowel, it will combine, so ' then e gives you é, ` then a gives you à etc.
If you don't follow it with anything that can take the accent, it will then generate the character followed by your non-accented letter, which is fine some of the time, but not always what you need.
So...

**To get them to print on their own, tap the space bar.**

Pic from Win 7 - The US international displays this behaviour, the UK doesn't.

[image]

Comment: @grawity - Never tried til now... first press does nothing, as anticipated, second press then generates two of them. Been testing it some more, it doesn't silently discard, it suddenly generates both chars if the following letter can't take the accent. Only space-bar generates *just* the required char.