# How to remove unneeded ENG International keyboard layout from Windows 10 permanently?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

After every update or restart Windows 10 adds English International keyboard layout.

In Settings > Time & Language > Region and Language > Preffered languages > English (Unites States) I click "Options"

[image]

And there is only US QWERTY keyboard.

However, the tray icon gives two English choices:
ENG US, ENG INTL, LIT.

[image]

So to remove it I have to go back to the Preferred languages > English (United States) I click "Options" 
Then "Add a keyboard" and then "add "United States-International". Close Settings.

Open Settings again. Now go to Preferred languages (as described before), click on English (United States) > Options and remove "United States-International".
Close Settings. Now the tray keyboard list will not have ENG INTL options!

[image]

My question is how to permanently remove International layout from the list so that I don't have to do this every time after Windows updates?

Comment: @Ramhound: this question is not duplicate of linked questions. The OP not asking how to remove question, but how to prevent it from adding it back. No answers is the linked questions solves this.

Comment: @Liero - If you don't believe this is a duplicate, then vote to reopen the question, I was only **one of two** users who voted to closed this question as a duplicate.  **As a user with a ton of experience in Windows I believe this to be a duplicate.**  The title of this question is literally, "How to remove ...", so I respectfully disagree that this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @Ramhound: I probably does not have enough reputation on this forum, I can't vote

Comment: @Liero - Everyone has enough reputation to flag a question to be reopened.  However, even if you cannot flag this question to be reopened, I still was not the reason the question was closed.

Comment: @Ramhound - How can we flag this question to be reopened?

Comment: @PhilGoetz - **Why?** It’s a duplicate of an existing question with the correct and proper answer.  I can add about 3 more potential duplicate candidates.

Comment: @Ramhound - Okay, I see that some of the answers way down in the list on one of those other questions might work.  I'm trying them now.  So, if any of those answers work, then this question is duplicate.  But it's very unfortunate that the top 4 answers all don't work, and all have an order of magnitude more upvotes than the answers that might work.