# I can't change the display language of my computer

Tags: windows-10, language

So i've been having a problem this past month where the Latvian language keeps installing back after i've uninstalled it, and keeps switching the display language to it. And it does it in a way, where i can't switch to any other language, and after i uninstall it with lpksetup it comes back. I've tried everything at this point, but it keeps coming back, and when it does i can't switch my display language. Any help?

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you using?  Which edition of Windows are you using?  Be as specific as possible, exact build numbers, are always helpful.

Comment: Im using Window 10 Enterprise, Version 1803

Comment: See if the methods from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1340511/8672) help here.