# Cant remove Windows 10 additional languages

Tags: windows-10, language

Without a reason today two new languages appeared and I can't remove them. The Language setting does not display them so I have no idea how to get rid of these.

EDIT: I can't remove anything from the keyboard settings neither

[image]
[image]

*Solution*: [How to delete a keyboard layout in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10)

Second Method with removing registry entries worked

Comment: Does not help `Note that I am not talking about removing a language` by the author. Also the answers do not lead to the solution in my case

Comment: Are you sure? Not even method 2 in my answer?

Comment: @harrymc in my settings it only lists my US layout - not the german ones.

Comment: I'm talking about the Preloaded registry method, not about Settings.

Comment: @harrymc checking