# Windows 10 keyboard layout menu is contradicting itself

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I used to cycle between three keyboard settings:

- QWERTY
- French AZERTY
- Belgian AZERTY

I removed French AZERTY from the list, but since then, whenever I boot Windows I get contradicting information.

The keyboard layout popup screen (Win + Space) and the language bar (in the taskbar) both me I have the two AZERTYs available, but the language settings window tells me that I have the Belgian AZERTY and QWERTY (which is what I want):

[image]

The only way I can solve this is to remove the QWERTY entry, and then add it again. This **adds** the QWERTY option but it still doesn't remove the French AZERTY option:

[image]

This seems to fix the popup screen and the language bar (well, partially), but when I reboot I have to do it all over again.

**How do I get Windows 10 to actually give me the keyboard layouts that I've configured, instead of some presumably cached version?**

---

To pre-empt a possible comment, I only have one language (and thus keyboard layout list), this isn't a confusion with using the wrong group:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1340511/8672) can help.

Comment: @harrymc: It didn't fully resolve the issue, but it did lead me to an acceptable enough solution. Note that I needed to change the CURRENT_USER registry settings too, not the just .DEFAULT. Also, now my language changes when I move to Belgian AZERTY (which I don't want). But if you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I can't copy that answer here - the moderators would prefer that I close this post as duplicate of the other.

Comment: @harrymc: The _question_ isn't a duplicate from the one you linked. The answer simply touches on a similar enough issue. I'm no SU.SE expert but going by SE standards this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: If you insist. Which part of my linked answer helped in your case? I suppose the `Preload` registry key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [link](https://superuser.com/a/1340511/8672) posted in a comment on the question led me to an acceptable (though not ideal) solution.

> **Method 2 : Preloaded**
>
> 1. Use regedit to navigate to `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload`.
>      You will find there the list of keyboards that are preloaded at boot.
> 2. Find the keyboard identifier among the list of
>      [Keyboard Identifiers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-language-pack-default-values)
> 3. Delete the key.

I had to perform this action for **both** `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

After that, the two expected keyboard layouts (QWERTY/Belgian AZERTY) were being shown on startup.

There are a few side effects though:

- The Belgian AZERTY language is set to NL instead of EN, which is not what I want.
- I have not found a way to make the Belgian AZERTY the default instead of QWERTY.

But this at least solves the core issue at hand. If anyone finds a solution that doesn't have these side effects, I'll happily give them the answer tick.