# Input languages mixed up after user switch

Tags: windows-10, input-languages

Running the latest version of Windows 10 (but same thing in 1903 as well) I often stumble into a particularly annoying bug.
I have two user accounts with different input language pairs (eng/rus and eng/ukr) and when switching user accounts I get my input languages broken (i.e. instead of eng/rus it would show eng/ukr or eng/rus/rus) and my typing experience is terrible.

I contacted MS support a number of times and it was awful. They tried all workarounds they could think of (including clean Windows install) but nothing helps. Ultimately they asked me to post a Windows Feedback post but of course it just hangs there with no comment or work done.

How do I get the reported Windows bug to get actually fixed?

I understand I can switch to Linux but I'm afraid of other bugs I can encounter there too.

The screenshot above demonstrates how another language option is added for no reason.

[image]

EDIT

Attached registry screenshots per comments

[image]

Comment: (Remark: Switching to Linux from Windows is not that easy.) I think you are getting a problem with the preloaded languages being modified by the two logins. Check Method 2 in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1340511/8672).

Comment: @harrymc No, look at the screenshot

Comment: Please use `regedit` to navigate to `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload`. Reboot, take screenshot, switch user, take screenshot, then post both screenshots.

Comment: @harrymc what is this 2000 language code? https://ibb.co/0cwJVpw

Comment: No idea : Delete and reboot to see.

Comment: @harrymc here's three screenshots: after reboot (2 languages - good), after user switch to user 2 (3 languages - good), and then after user switch back to user1 (3 languages - bad).

Comment: I do wonder what the code 2000 is, and why the two users have different preload lists (I'd think the .default user is global?)

Comment: Here's another puzzle: in the next registry key I can see a substitute for 2000 -> 419: https://ibb.co/4f8dQPQ

Comment: You provided us the key for the default user, what about keys, for your actual users?  When this behavior happens, are you switching users or logging out of the user, that might make a difference.  Please edit your question instead of submitting comment.