# The file \Windows\en-US\explorer.exe.mui cannot be removed

Tags: windows, permissions

The permissions of the file were change to Administrators allowing full control. I have followed this steps:

1. Run the cmd with Administrators rights
2. On the cmd, the command `RMDIR \Windows\en-US` was executed

> All the files were removed from the folder, but the **explorer.exe.mui**

3. On the cmd, the command `DEL \Windows\en-US\explorer.exe.mui` was executed

> C:\Windows\en-US\explorer.exe.mui
>
> Access is denied.

The security setting of the file are changed. I opened the cmd with administration privileges. Does any one know why "Access is denied" is displayed?

Comment: Why remove it? Windows 10?

Comment: I am deleting some keyboard layouts following the first answer from this thread https://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10
If you see one of the comments under the answer. There is a user who had not only to remove the registry keys, but also the en-US folder. I am having the same issue of this user, therefore I am trying his solution.

Comment: Yes, Windows 10

Comment: That folder holds half of each critical Windows file. Windows system files are divided into two. So Explorer.exe holds code and Explorer.exe.mui holds the resources. Both explorer files are open (if you can see your desktop) and memory mapped as all exe files are (that means ALL open programs are paging files). You can't delete an open file.

Comment: @Mark What kind of resources holds the Explorer.exe.mui files? In which level are the files on this folder critical? I am puzzled

Comment: I deleted all the files in this folder, but the Explorer.exe.mui and my computer still works.

Comment: Does notepad? MUI holds the language specific resources (and for Explorer nothing to do with keyboards) such as menu text, error messages, shortcut keys. If you aren't running EN-US English then you are using a mui file from another folder.