# duplicated language win 10

Tags: windows-10, input-languages, language-bar

There is a lot of questions like this over the Internet. But I still can not resolve my problem. I have three languages in lang-bar, but I need only two.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a keyboard layout in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10)

Comment: @Ramhound, no. As you can see, I don't have three languages in the settings

Comment: The duplicate question is about getting rid of the extra keyboard layouts.  Have you tried the answer to the duplicate?

Comment: Yes, when I press "Options" on "English (United States)" in the "Preferred Languages", there is the only single US QWERTY keyboard.

Comment: I tried method 2 from your post, but it still does not work

Comment: @Ramhound method 2 from your link still works. I tried with the second attempt yesterday and do not have this problem yet. But I need to test for two more days, I know windows can remove 3d language after reboot.

Comment: So, it's still ok. https://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10 method 2 helped me

Comment: It's back :( And deleting en-US Dvorak d0x00010409 does not help now. I installed en-UK as default and display lang, the second en-US keyboard left after this. So, I reinstalled en-US and removed en-UK. Now it's ok again