# Keyboard Layout Change Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

My keyboard layout is quite messy.
I study in Germany, my physical keyboard layout is German (QWERTZ), but since my program is in English, so is my OS language. In addition to that, I also quite frequently type in Russian for uni and work. (I have added Cyrillic stickers to my keyboard)

My problem is as follows:
When I want to switch between keyboard layout settings, there are 4 layouts in my shortcut settings (German, German (Austrian), English, Russian), making it a pain in the ass to use hotkeys to switch. However, when I go to Settings > Time & Language > Language, there are 3 languages: English, German, Russian (No German (Austrian), which is in my shortcut).

Is there any way to remove English and German(Austrian) from the shortcut panel?

Note that the remove option for English is blacked out, going through options first leads to the same dead end.

Language Settings:

[image: Language Settings]

Language Shortcuts:

[image: Language Shortcuts]

Comment: You need to set some other language as a default one first and move it up, after which you can remove English. for German you need to enter Settings > Time & Language > Language and in the Options of German just remove one of 2 keyboards (you have 2 layouts for one language)

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find these languages under **PC Settings** > **Time & Language** > **Region & language** > **Languages**, I would suggest to try the following methods.

1. Use regedit to navigate to following registry keys, where you will find there the list of keyboards that are preloaded at  oot.

**HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload**

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload**

**HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\User Profile**

**HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\User Profile System Backup**

2. Find the keyboard identifier among the list of [Keyboard Identifiers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-language-pack-default-values)
3. Delete the key.

For more methods, please refer to this similar thread: [How to delete a keyboard layout in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10?rq=1)