# How to add languages/regional settings without adding keyboard layouts in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, language, regional-settings

My setup is this.

- Country or region: Russia
- Regional format: English (United Kingdom)
- Display language: English (US)
- Input methods: English (US), Russian

With the newer Windows builds, when I set the regional format to English (UK), English (UK) gets added to the list of languages with its own keyboard. And I can't remove it. If I remove English (UK) from the list of languages, my regional format gets reverted to English (US).

Previously, I could select keyboard layouts manually with the Control Panel applet. Now there is no such an option.

Is there a way to set regional settings to English (UK) (and possibly use other features like spellcheck and display language preferences) without adding keyboard layouts?

Illustrations:
[Regional Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xafmV.png)
[Languages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gtsa.png)
[Keyboards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPuVB.png)

Comment: Try the methods in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1340511/8672) to delete the extra keyboard.

Comment: @harrymc I've seen that, but the first one doesn't work, obviously (it's the only keyboard in the list under a particular language, and as the only one, it can't be removed, the button is disabled). And the second one seems problematic; I'll start editing the registry by hand only as a last resort.

Answer (score 6):

I've found a workaround. I wonder for how long it will work, though: the Control Panel features get removed with each Windows release.

The trick is to set the regional format through Control Panel, not Settings.

1. Set up everything except the regional format through Settings:

   - [Settings/Region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6ySe.png)
   - [Settings/Language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtFIp.png)
2. Go to Control Panel - Region (you can get there via Settings - Region - Additional date, time & regional settings). Set the regional format there.

   - [Settings/Region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ivsfq.png)
   - [Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzRtF.png)
   - [Control Panel/Region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utRMf.png)
3. Additional languages won't be installed. This is the desired outcome.

   As a bonus, you can also customize the regional settings outside of the pre-defined options with *Additional settings*.

   - [Control Panel/Region/Additional settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcyr1.png)

Comment: It still works! I agree that it might not still work several years from now.

Answer (score 0):

I found a more legit workaround:

1. Add the keyboard layouts (including English UK) through Settings
2. Set the regional format, speech, etc. to your preferred language (in this case, English UK)
3. Click on the English UK layout
4. Click on Options
5. Click on Add a keyboard
6. Select US QWERTY
7. Change the order so that US QWERTY will be above the UK layout
8. Remove the UK layout

Now you can enjoy the English UK language everywhere without affecting your layout.

Comment: Will this not result in two English layouts when switching with the shortcut? Just like with US and UK.

Comment: nope, because you are left with a single layout that you can edit.