# How to prevent Windows 11 from automatically adding keyboard layouts

Tags: keyboard, language, windows-11

why en-ZW added to my keyboard language?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a keyboard layout in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10)

Answer (score -1):

The temporary solution that came to my mind was that I went to the settings and re-added the same language to my list and deleted it again and it was fixed and if we can write a script for this process. Is it good