# Disable a keyboard input language temporarily

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, input-languages

I have installed a few different languages on my system but I usually use one of them and English, I want to temporarily disable all the other ones so that I can switch between that language and English with a single <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. I am a windows user. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

My idea is based on this
[answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1340511/8672)
for deleting a keyboard layout from the registry:

> 1. Use regedit to navigate to following registry keys, where you will find there the list of keyboards that are preloaded at boot.
>
> - `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload`
> - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload`
> - `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\User Profile`
> - `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\User Profile System Backup`
>
> 2. Find the keyboard identifier among the list of [Keyboard Identifiers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-language-pack-default-values)
> 3. Delete the key.

The evolution of this idea is to use `regedit` to export the above
four registry keys to two `.reg` files for each of your wanted
configurations (after configuring the languages manually).

Once the files are created, executing them will set the wanted
languages.

Note that for an exported `.reg` key that looks like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload]
...
```

You should add a line to delete the existing key, to clean up before
importing, which will make it look like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload]

[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload]
...
```