# Cannot remove US Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, windows-11, language

I have a mildly infuriating problem where I cannot remove the US keyboard no matter what on Windows 11.

I currently live in Japan and the Japanese Input Method can very conveniently switch between both English and Japanese input modes making the US keyboard completely redundant.

What makes it even more annoying is that Windows decides to default to using the US input Method randomly on it's own. The keybind for switching between English and Japanese on the Japanese IME is ctrl + ` but on the US input that keybind switches windows. So when I try to type something in Japanese and English shows up, I instictively press ctrl + ``
to swap to Japanese but instead to my annoyance it brings up another window.

I am at my wits end, I've removed english completely from my system, tried all the suggested methods such as installing the english pack and uninstalling it again. I've fiddled with regedit and I've tried looking the problem up in Japanese forums but have found nothing that would work.

Even if I can't get rid of it, simply stopping it from magically defaulting itself to US would be a god-send.

Comment: Did you try the Time and Language settings in Windows 11 Settings.  That will no eliminate the US Keyboard, but it should allow you to set an alternate default ketboard

Comment: Using a Japanese keyboard might not be very common (I myself don't really understand the context of the problem: I had to look up IME, I'm not sure if you are talking about the keyboard layout that is being switched, etc.), if you explain it from an outsider's perspective you might get more help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a keyboard layout in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10)

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've already tried the method linked by harrymc. I've also sort of tried the suggestion given by John, I've left the english pack installed and set Japanese as my default but my system will still randomly switch to using the english IME. To answer Albin, IME is basically the keyboard option, since the Japanese keyboard is also capable of entering English mode so I used IME to clarify it's switching out of my Japanese keyboard on it's own completely unprompted in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure it out.

The culprit appears to be explorer patcher which I have been using to uncombine taskbar windows, it's been automatically adding the US keyboard to my registry and setting it to default for some odd reason.

I'm not sure how helpful it is since it's a pretty niche problem but here's how I solved it:

- Reset Explorer Patcher to its default settings
- Go to AppData/Roaming and delete the ExplorerPatcher folder
- Uninstall Explorer Patcher
- Open Regedit and navigate to `HKEY_USERS\\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload` and delete the unwanted keyboards
- Sign out and sign back in
- Reinstall Explorer Patcher