# set default keyboard layout in windows 11

Tags: windows, keyboard

I use two different keyboard layouts but every I boot up my pc I have to change to the second layout.

How do I make it the default one?

Comment: Start, Settings, Time and Language, Typing.  You should be able to set default there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This option is well-hidden in Windows 11, so you will have to
go into the registry.

- Find your
  [Keyboard identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-language-pack-default-values?view=windows-11#keyboard-identifiers)
  in the list and note it down
- Run `regedit`
- Position to the registry key
  `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload`
- You will see your two keyboard layout listed, where your layout
  is in the item named `2`
- Right-click the item named `1`, select "Rename" and change it to `3`
- Likewise rename `2` to `1`
- Now rename `3` to `2` to swap the order
- Reboot for your change to take effect.

Comment: For me this does change the selected layout at boot screen, but after logging in I still have the wrong layout.

Comment: @avysk: Check the other registry keys from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1340511/8672).

Comment: `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload` looked correct but I have deleted it anyway and my problem is gone. Thanks!

Comment: I can rename the registry only if I start the `regedit` in admin mode.

Answer (score 20):

In `Time & language` > `Typing` > `Advanced keyboard settings`, you can select a keyboard as the default. (tested under Windows 11 Pro 22H2, OS build 22621.1635)

Example showing United States-Dvorak as default keyboard:
[image: Example]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No need for the registry. Demerits for Microsoft for making this nearly impossible to find without a web search.

Comment: For me does not work.

Comment: I am using a custom keyboard layout (created with Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator), and it does not appear in this list

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need the registry if you want to change the keyboard layout within a language (aka "Language options"):

[image: Drop down of language]

[image: Language options / Keyboard layouts]

If you have multi languages installed (like in my example, I am running  Windows 11 (Version 21H2 Build 22000.856) with English + German installed), one should be able to change the default keyboard layout without the need to change the registry but by just putting the language in question to the top position:

Settings -> Time & language -> Language & region: move the keyboard layout in question to the top position.

Comment: For me does not work.