# How to remove a third language (English (USA) 319 Latin) that appears to my keyboard layout in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, keyboard-layout, language, input-languages

I have a Dell Inspiron 14 5425 laptop running Windows 11. Recently, I noticed that a third language has been added to my keyboard layout, which is `English (USA) 319 Greek-Latin` or something like that. I am not sure what this `319` means. This has been causing a lot of confusion as I am not familiar with the layout and cannot find the characters I need when I write, or change to the correct language with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

I have tried deleting a language from the registry by removing the following values from the `Keyboard Layout\Preload` key:

- `00000409`
- `00000408`
- `d0010409`

(i am not sure which one of them is the `319` weird language setting)

However, when I restarted my laptop, all three languages reappear in the registry, even if the keyboard layout was actually fixed.

I have also tried removing the language from Windows GUI `Language preferences` settings, but there is no option to delete it.

The only way I have been able to fix this issue is by deleting all languages from the keyboard layout, restarting my laptop, and then reapplying my preferred settings. However, this is a time-consuming process and I would like to find a permanent solution.

Can anyone suggest a way to remove the third language from my keyboard layout permanently? I would greatly appreciate any help or advice on this matter. Thank you.

Comment: I am highly confident that it's 00000408 based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-input-locales-for-windows-language-packs?view=windows-11) documentation. `d0010409` is a Dvorak English layout while `00000409` is a US English layout. What locale is your user profile configured to use?  Screenshots are best way to share information in addition to the text. It would also be helpful to see the formatted output of the PowerShell command `Get-WinUserLanguageList`. Without this information I can't provide an answer to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a keyboard layout in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10)

Comment: Thanks so much! Well, as I explained the third language is removed now that I signed out and in.  From the powershell command you suggested I got the following (the Scriptname of the result is "Latin" in greek which is suspicous:

Comment: The problematic one is currently not below.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-WinUserLanguageList

LanguageTag     : en-US
Autonym         : English (United States)
EnglishName     : English
LocalizedName   : Αγγλικά (ΗΠΑ)
ScriptName      : Λατινικά
InputMethodTips : {0409:00000409}
Spellchecking   : True
Handwriting     : False

LanguageTag     : el
Autonym         : Ελληνικά
EnglishName     : Modern Greek (1453-)
LocalizedName   : Ελληνικά
ScriptName      : Ελληνική
InputMethodTips : {0408:00000408}
Spellchecking   : True
Handwriting     : False

Comment: @harrymc thanks so much. I deleted it with the firstmethod of your provided link, but in the registry it is still there. if idelete the value from registry, it reappears on restart. Even if it appears in registry, it doesnt appear in the taskbar, but I am afraid that at some point it wil lreturn!!

Comment: Check all the registry locations from the link. If it still comes back, this must be done by some installed app.

Comment: hi @harrymc it only existed in the first location from the link (the one I deleted from in the first place). Yes it can be an app that brings it back, maybe deepL translating software or some windows office. I don't know

Comment: can that come from league of legends? now i have this new weird thing that it came back but i cannot find it in registry at all. can i somehow delete it with not causing system error? or do a script to prevent it?