# Ideas for a script to check and fix parasitic keyboard layout?

Tags: windows, windows-11, keyboard-layout, bug

I've been having this problem since Windows 7. It's there on Windows 10 and 11 - the same problem!

I am an American with an American laptop, living in the UK.

I install Windows as "Region: United Kingdom" because I want the time zone, date format and other goodies to match my life here.

However, Windows is being super "clever" and "helpful" by adding a UK layout to my operating system GUI, which is super fun when typing passwords and getting locked out because the symbols are switched between layouts...

Also super fun that I've been using computers since 1994 and I am used to switch between my 3 languages but when I have 4 - I am landing on the wrong language all the time - it's muscle memory...

Sometimes, I can Install and uninstall the UK layout and it disappears. Today, this trick didn't work.

It's super inconsistent too. Like, I could have a whole year without this problem and then "heeeyyy here's a keyboard layout that I am sure you need, you're welcome!"

Is there a script I can write, and run upon bootup, to check if an unwanted keyboard layout has crept in and then knock out that layout?

Any fractions of that script and/or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10/1340511#1340511) help?