# Don't switch keyboard layout if fast typing

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, printing, keyboard-layout

### 1. Briefly

Keyboard layout sometimes not switch for me, if I print my texts fast. It would be nice, if my keyboard layout switched each time, when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. I will approach any built-in solution or gratis software.

---

### 2. Detail

I have Windows 64-bit EN; The problem is reproduced many times in Windows 32-bit. I have 2 keyboard layouts — English and Russian. I switch my keyboard layout use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> hotkeys. Sometimes layouts not switched for me, if I print fast. If I print slow, the problem is not reproduced for me.

For example, in a demonstration GIF keyboard layout not switched for me 2 times. In GIF one can see that I correct press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

***Original GIF:***

[image: Original GIF]

***0,07 speed:***

[image: 0.07]

The problem reproduced for me in Notepad or any others applications.

---

### 3. Did not help

1. I don't find setting in `Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language`.
2. I don't find on Internet any possible solutions to this problem.

---

### 4. Do not offer

1. Please, do not offer use another shortcuts for switching between keyboard layouts. I don't want it. I used to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.
2. Yes, I use a program to change words, printing in the wrong keyboard layout — [**Mahou**](https://gitea.com/BladeMight/Mahou) — but sometimes I need switching between keyboard layouts manually.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you try in default Notepad, and take a look at your taskbar?

Comment: @BladeMight, problem reproduced for me in Notepad: **http://i.imgur.com/LMSs7QW.gif** . Thanks.

Comment: What about your taskbar's current keyboard layout? And also try switching layout with one key(Mahou have this feature) and say how it works. And which English layout do you have English(US) or another? If another there is problem with English(US) to appear sometimes by itself even if it not selected. And since it is Windows 10 try using Win+Space instead of Alt+Shift.

Comment: @BladeMight, // **1.** I use my own Russian and English keyboard layouts (my Colemak modifications), but problem is reproduced for me in default `QWERTY/ЙЦУКЕН` keyboard layouts. // **2.** When I switch between my keyboard layout, I see in taskbar only `ENG` and `РУС`. I [**disable Ctrl+Shift**](http://superuser.com/a/706636/572069) and `Right_Ctrl` [**use SharpKeys**](http://superuser.com/a/36922/572069), that I don't get `ENG/US` keyboard layout.

Comment: // **3.** In Mahou: `Switch layout by Key` → `Caps Lock` → `Apply` → when I switch between keyboard layouts use `Caps Lock`, I get `ENG/US` and `РУС` keyboard layouts. [**Screenshot**](http://i.imgur.com/w8tr7w1.png) I don't want 3rd keyboard layout `ENG/US`, I want only `ENG` and `RUS` keyboard layouts. So I don't use Mahou for switching. // Thanks.

Comment: OK i see, you have a modified keyboard layout which is why ENG/US appearing randomly and that is why your switching not works sometimes.

Comment: See this issue: http://superuser.com/questions/685078/how-do-i-remove-english-us-from-windows-8-1

Comment: I fixed it for me by going to advanced settings in `Control Panel > Clock, Language and Region > Change input methods` http://thewindowsclub.thewindowsclubco.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/language-control-panel.jpg and in `Override for default input method` http://i.imgur.com/nuz6gWp.jpg select your English and then logout and login and try everything again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52176/discussion-between---and-blademight).

Comment: the Mahou repository is not available anymore

Comment: @LogicDaemon, Mahou repository migrated from GitHub to Gitea. I updated the link in my question. Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных btw, the problem trigger is, as you can see on the gif you posted, is that you're pressing Shift+Alt, not Alt+Shift. These are different combinations, since pressing and releasing Alt with nothing in between causes the window menu to open.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem,
I've solved it as following:

1. Go to **Control panel**
2. Click **Clock and Region**
3. Click **Region**
4. Select tab **Administrative**
5. in the section **Language for non-Unicode programs** click button **Change system locale...**
6. then choose  **Current system locale** to your locale
7. Click **OK** button
8. it will ask you to **Restart Program** then choose **Restart Now**

Comment: Tip: if you add a space between the number and the following text (`1. something` instead of `1.something`), it will get treated as list item and formatted correctly.