# How to delete a keyboard layout in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

The problem is, I have two input languages and I can't remove English!

Video here -->> 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZhuapkxiik

[image: (Screenshot) See for yourself...]

When playing games I sometimes switch the languages and it screws things up... I can't believe this bug still exists.

First of all, I've read all possible solutions from the search, there are a few:

[How to delete a keyboard layout in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10)

[How do I remove English (US) from Windows 8.1?](https://superuser.com/questions/685078/how-do-i-remove-english-us-from-windows-8-1)

The mentioned solutions were to remove the unwanted Language from the "Input Methods" in the Language options. But there is no entry of that! (see screenshot)

Somebody suggested then to re-add the missing Language and remove it afterwards but I can't add it, its not in the list as well! There is only "Indian" English which is something else, adding and removing it had no effect. (see screenshot)

So no luck with Language Options - maybe I'm missing something?

Also somebody mentioned to look into the registry and delete the second input entry, but I've got only one! (see screenshot)

Please help, I'm out of ideas!

Comment: Ensure that Windows Update service is enabled and you have an Internet connection. Try in PC Settings->Apps->Apps & features>Manage optional features->Add a feature to install everything that is English (US). Next try PC Settings->Time & language>Region & language>Add a language.

Comment: Hez Harrymc! Thanks for your answer! I'm afraid you did not understand my problem. I want to REMOVE ENGLISH from the layout. I can't add it, because it is probably already there but its not showing!

Comment: It just seemed to me that after it's properly installed, then it may be possible to properly remove it.

Comment: Interesting! But nevertheless I have got all the english languages already installed.

Comment: This is a question on the same topic [link](https://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10)

Comment: The Solutions mentioned there do not apply, since i do not have the english entry in the "Input Methods" list.

Comment: Is English currently the default language? If so I think you'd have to set German as default language before you can remove English

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a keyboard input option in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1025105/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-input-option-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 2):

I Solved it, go to Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language
Add Language English (United States) - or what ever ur Layout was - then just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I had US Keyboard and UK Keyboard.  Language was English (Australia).  I wanted to get rid of UK Keyboard.   Go to Region and Language.  Click on English (Australia).  Showed the two keyboards.  Click remove on UK Keyboard.